# Without regex reduce multiple spaces in a string to one in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

While answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053458/python-loop-through-string-in-nested-for-loops) question I had a doubt regarding how to reduce multiple spaces in a string to one in Python without using regex. Say the string is as follows:

```
s = "Mary    had    a little lamb"
```

The first solution that came to my mind was

```
' '.join(s.split())
```

But this will not conserve leading and trailing spaces if the string was something like

```
s = "    Mary    had    a little lamb  "
```

In order to conserve leading and trailing spaces (if present), I came up with a slightly different approach where I added a dummy character to the starting and ending of the string (in this case a '-') which I later removed after the split. The code is as follows:

```
' '.join(('-' + s + '-').split())[1:-1]
```

Is there any other built in function or another pythonic way to do this?

**Edit:**
By conserving leading and trailing spaces, I meant that in case there are multiple spaces at the beginning and/or at the end of the string, these multiple spaces should also be reduced to a single space

Comment: I liked your solution. Other than that I'd go with a regex. Though yours definitely requires a comment, a regex might not.

Comment: when I try your solution with the dummy characters, it doesn't conserve the leading/trailing whitespace, I don't understand..

Comment: @Totem, A correction: The solution that I mentioned would reduce multiple spaces at the beginning and/or at the end of the string to a single space. It will not conserve all the spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "    Mary    had    a little lamb  "
res = ''.join(' ' if is_space else ''.join(chars) for is_space, chars in groupby(s, str.isspace))
#  Mary had a little lamb
```

Comment: I was just writing this up, although I decided against `str.isspace` because that would pick up tabs too.

Comment: @DSM yes... I was being lazy... although... `lambda ch: ch == ' '` is not really much more effort :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x if x[-1]==' ' and y==' ' else x+y, s) if s else ''
' Mary had a little lamb '
```

Comment: Hi alexander, I'm using python3.3 seems like reduce() is not present in 3.x version

Comment: @Pulimon It is moved to `functools` in Python3: `from functools import reduce`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = "    Mary    had    a little lamb  "
>>> s
'    Mary had a little lamb  '
>>> len0 = len(s)
>>> s = s.rstrip()
>>> len1 = len(s)
>>> s = s.lstrip()
>>> s = " ".join(s.split())
>>> print s
Mary had a little lamb
>>> s = s.rjust(len1).ljust(len0)
>>> s
'    Mary had a little lamb  '
```

This code will preserve spaces. I know it's not required, but I'll just leave this here.

Comment: Hi loa_in_: By leading and trailing spaces I meant that if there are multiple spaces at the beginning or at the end of a string, those multiple spaces should also be reduced to a single space. In this solution you conserve all the spaces

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fine for me.

```
test_str = "    Mary    had    a little lamb  "
while "  " in test_str:
    test_str = test_str.replace("  ", " ")

print test_str # yield ' Mary had a little lamb '
```

Answer (score 0):

(len(s) - len(s.lstrip()) * ' ' + ' '.join(s.lstrip().rstrip().split()) + (len(s) - len(s.rstrip()) * ' '

Comment: This doesn't preserve leading and trailing spaces, as OP asked for in the question.